# 8086 - Reverse MUL operation with 2 registers

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm attempting to reverse a MUL operation that has overflows to the DX register.

```
mov ax, 1234h
mov dx, 109h
mul dx

; ax = C024
; dx = 0007
```

How can I divide DX and AX by `109h`?
I'm trying to get the original AX through the resulted AX and DX (from the `MUL` operation).

Comment: Have you tried `DIV`?

Comment: My question is, how do you divide both registers and keep the value identical? Dividing each one separately and then combining them is not the same, since `dx` is `7h`, but it should be suffixed with `ax` before division.

Comment: I would suggest taking a closer look at the specification of the `DIV r/m16` instruction. In particular, what registers does it use as inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MUL` of 16-bit values gives a 32-bit result, so the CPU splits the 32-bit result into two 16-bit registers, like `dx2 = (ax1 * dx1) >> 16` and `ax2 = (ax1 * dx1) & 0xFFFF`.

`DIV` can divide a 32-bit value by a 16-bit value, where the 32-bit numerator is split into two 16-bit registers, which are the same `dx` and `ax` registers.

With this in mind (using different registers so that the value you need later for the divisor isn't overwritten by the results of the multiplication):

```
mov bx, 1234h
mov ax, 109h

mul bx                ;dx:ax = ax * bx = 0x0109 * 0x1234

div bx                ;ax = dx:ax / bx = 0x0109 * 0x1234 / 0x1234 = 0x0109
                      ;dx = dx:ax % bx = 0x0109 * 0x1234 % 0x1234 = 0
```